# Find logical errors in the proof

Tags: logic, relations

I'm finding it really hard to find the logical errors in this proof. I'm still new at this and trying to learn it.

> Claim: for all $n$ is in set $\mathbb{N}$(Natural numbers), if $2n+1$ is a multiple of $3$ then,
>       $n^2+1$ is a multiple of $3$.
>
> Proof: by contrapositive. Assume that $2n+1$ is not a multiple of $3$.
>
> It follows that
>
> - If $n = 3k+1$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ then $n^2+1 = 9k^2+6k+2$ is not a multiple of $3$.
> - If $n = 3k+2$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ then $n^2+1 = 9k^2+12k+5$ is not a multiple of $3$.
> - If $n = 3k+3$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ then $n^2+1 = 9k^2+18k+10$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Where are the logical errors in the proof? I don't understand.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contrapositive of the statement "If $A$, then $B$" is the statement "If not $B$, then not $A$".

For the statement

> If $2n+1$ is a multiple of $3$, then $n^2+1$ is a multiple of $3$

the contrapositive is

> If $n^2+1$ is not a multiple of $3$, then $2n+1$ is not a multiple of $3$.

However, the proof assumed that $2n+1$ is not a multiple of $3$ and then proved that $n^2+1$ is not a multiple of $3$, i.e. the proof proved the statement

> If $2n+1$ is not a multiple of $3$, then $n^2+1$ is not a multiple of $3$.

This is the inverse, not the contrapositive of the original statement. Proving the inverse of a statement is not equivalent to proving the original statement. Hence, that proof doesn't prove what it is supposed to prove.

Comment: ohhhh thanks so much, also what could a counter example for the claim be? I assumed it was if n = 0, both equations would equal 1 and thats not a multiple of 3. Is this correct? @JimmyK4542

Comment: A counterexample to a statement of the form "If $A$, then $B$" is an example where $A$ is true, but $B$ is false. So you need to find an example where $2n+1$ is a multiple of $3$, but $n^2+1$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Comment: Ohh okay, I understand now. Thank you for your help! @JimmyK4542